# Ace editor version upgrade

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm a member of a team with more than 20 developers. The ACE editor is the one main editor we used from long time now.

Now, We want to upgrade the ACE editor version, but I don't know which version of ace editor they have used. The current ace version is 1.4.2 but I can't see any version details in the cdn js, and it was taken from this below link :

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src-noconflict/ace.js

and the latest version cdn also doesn't have any version details and the team also don't have any version history.

I know, cdnjs is build generated and If I want to update ace, I need to update the followings too :

1. ace
2. ext-language_tools
3. mode-javascript
4. theme-clouds
5. theme-monokai
6. worker-javascript

If I update to the newer one,  ext-language_tools throws me an error, few of the events were missed in the newer one.

Is there's any performance update over the older one with a new version of ace editor, with old ace editor version team have done few custom things with ext-language_tools.js.

Things I want to know before updating this :

1. Is there's any performance update over the older one with a new version of ace editor
2. Can I update all the 6 files with new version except ext-language_tools.js, because it has some customized events.

Any help on this really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src-noconflict/ace.js always points to the latest version of the editor published to ace-builds so it doesn't help. But you can get the version of ace by running `ace.version` in the console, unless it is a very old version it should be defined.

If you have to modify ext-language_tools.js to add events, then it is better to open an issue on ace bugtracker asking to add those events

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can i use ace.js latest with ext-language-tools older version ?

Comment: If it doesn't throw errors, you may, but that is not tested, and you may run into bugs

Comment: since I need to update ace version, is there any benefits like performance improvements ?  where I can get this details. Would be really helpful If you help me on this

Comment: there is a changelog file in the repository, there have been several bugfixes, performance improvements and new features, depends on which version you use now